# Setting Cache to maximum level in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I have a site that serves mostly static data from a database, so I'd like to have the maximum caching possible. The database is very weak and slow.

I am using shared hosting, so am limited to the [OutputCache] on the Controller and web.config

Is there a "max" strategy?

Ian

Comment: There's nothing wrong with setting the cache duration to 60 minutes. At most you'll have 24 calls to the database per day, which is nothing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try going for the below option, it should give you 2147483647 seconds (24855 days) max duration for int32:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = int.MaxValue)]
```

Please note however that it is not guaranteed that your cache will be preserved exactly for the amount of time that you specify; it depends on memory utilization - if memory becomes too low, cache will be removing data automatically.